# getting data from a gridview into an access database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have it mostly working but i can't get all the gridview data into the database it's only taking the first line of data here's the code:

```
Try
    Dim pid As String
    Dim pname As String
    Dim Connection As OleDbConnection
    Connection = New OleDbConnection()
    Dim connolaString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data/my_products.mdb;") + ";Persist Security Info=True"
    Connection.ConnectionString = connolaString
    Dim commander As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    commander.Connection = Connection
    commander.CommandText = "INSERT INTO prdtemp ( pid, pname ) VALUES ( @pid, @pname )"
    Connection.Open()
    For x As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        pid = GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Text
        pname = GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Text
        commander.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid)
        commander.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", pname)
        commander.ExecuteNonQuery()
        commander.Dispose()
    Next
    Connection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    lblMessage.Text = (ex.Message)
End Try
```

and for some reason the (ex.message) says connection property not initialized although like i said it's getting the first row of the gridview only. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you call the `commander.Dispose()` method in your loop. That's going to release all the object's resources and break things on your second loop iteration.

Edit: I would advise you wrap the `OleDbCommand` with a `Using` statement which handles the object disposal for you when it exits the `Using` block.

Refer to the example here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7shabkb8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

I haven't tested the revised code below, but it should solve your issue.

```
Try
    Dim pid As String
    Dim pname As String
    Dim Connection As OleDbConnection
    Connection = New OleDbConnection()
    Dim connolaString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data/my_products.mdb;") + ";Persist Security Info=True"
    Using commander As New OleDbCommand(connolaString)
        commander.Connection = Connection
        commander.CommandText = "INSERT INTO prdtemp ( pid, pname ) VALUES ( @pid, @pname )"
        Connection.Open()
        For x As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            pid = GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Text
            pname = GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Text
            commander.Parameters.Clear()
            commander.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid)
            commander.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", pname)
            commander.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        Connection.Close()
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    lblMessage.Text = (ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with "Using" statement i can understand it but i'm not sure i can apply it properly. would it be too much trouble if i asked you to provide me with a sample code?

Comment: @Daniel Darko - Have you looked at the code example on the page I linked to (it's at the bottom of the page)?

Comment: yes but honestly since i'm a beginner i got a bit confused and i'm not sure on how to use it with my code

Comment: this actually stopped all copying and i'm still getting the same ex.message

Comment: @Daniel Darko - Weird. OK, well try going back to your original code and simply removing the `commander.Dispose()` method. Also, you'll need to add the `commander.Parameters.Clear()` method because if you don't, it will simply add to the Parameters collection over and over (each loop iteration - that's not what you want.)

Comment: hey man your solution was correct you just forgot to specify the connection string `Connection.ConnectionString = connolaString` just added this before `Using` blcok and it worked thanks alot you saved my hide